# UWP read registry from background task and feed information back to UI

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, uwp

I am a bit stuck and need advice on a couple of questions.
I am developing a UWP application to send a user notification in form of toast and active tile

In my solutions, I have added *Windows Runtime Component (Universal Windows)* which is performing background tasks on a time trigger.

What I am trying to solve (no luck so far)

1. Can Background Task read registry or WMI? is it possible at all?
2. How could I connect back to my background tasks to get the collected data when a user opens / re-opens the app

Answer (score 1):

> Can Background Task read registry or WMI? is it possible at all?

For security reason, UWP does not provide such api to access registry directly, The only way is that indirectly access registry with Win32 process from uwp. You can read registry values from a Win32 runFullTrust  process launched from a UWP application

> How could I connect back to my background tasks to get the collected data when a user opens / re-opens the app

You have many way to send the value back to UWP platform, such as store the key into app's local storage and retrieve from UWP platform,  Or use [AppService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service) to communicate desktop extension and uwp client. For more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service).

Comment: "You can read registry values from a Win32 runFullTrust process launched from a UWP application" - I can start a win32 process that from UWP app no problem, but I cannot find a way to start that process from Background task (Windows Runtime Component), If you have a small example I would appreciate that very much!

Comment: I'm afraid it could not be load in the Windows Runtime Component, you may try to use   [Brokered Windows Runtime components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps)

Answer (score 1):

You can not access registry from UWP app. UWP is sandbox. I do not know why registry access is required. However,  you can use UWP ApplicationDataContainer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings?view=winrt-19041) to store, retrieve and share any data as your desired object between your UWP app and background task.

Comment: I need to access Registry or WMI so I can store app configurations and control them from a central location as this is an app for enterprise. so far I can't find another way to central control user settings.